# How to create link for executable file and indicate work folder in batch or VBS?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, shortcut-file

OS: Windows 7

I am trying to create a link to the desktop folder via batch like this:

```
mklink "%userprofile%\Desktop\MyExe" "%~dp0\MyExe.exe"
```

The command worked, but how to indicate `MyExe.exe` execute at `"%~dp0"`? 
`MyExe.exe` looks like run at the current folder, so it can't load my config file.

**Update:**

Got the different problem by using VBS, run code in below will create a shortcut
for `C:\Users\jiu\Desktop\MyExe.exe`, But I want `MyExe.exe`.

```vbs
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
userProfilePath = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")
currParentFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
linkPath = userProfilePath + "\Desktop\MyExe.LNK"
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(linkPath)
    oLink.TargetPath = "MyExe.exe" 
    oLink.WorkingDirectory = currParentFolder
oLink.Save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the information you have provided, here's a strange looking batch file which should create your desktop shortcut for you:

```bat
;@Rundll32 AdvPack.dll,LaunchINFSection "%~0",,1
;@GoTo :EOF
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
[DefaultInstall]
ProfileItems=AddLnk
[AddLnk]
Name="MyExe",8,16
CmdLine=1,,"MyExe.exe"
InfoTip="Execute MyExe.exe"
WorkingDir=1
```

You can optionally modify:

- The shortcuts display name
  *by replacing the string inside the doublequotes on line `8`.*
- The name of the target executable
  *by replacing the string inside the doublequotes on line `9`.*
- The shortcuts description comment
  *by replacing the string inside the doublequotes on line `10`.*

Answer (score 0):

`mklink` doesn't create a `*.lnk` [***shortcut***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortcut_(computing)) but a [symbolic/hard ***link***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) which is just a new name for the physical file. As the link is in desktop, obviously the current folder will be desktop if you double click the link

You must create a [**shortcut**](https://ss64.com/nt/shortcut.html). One way of doing that is by using the below vbs script

```vbs
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
sLinkFile = strDesktop & "\MyExe.lnk"
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)

oLink.TargetPath = WScript.Arguments(0) & "\" & WScript.Arguments(1)
'  oLink.Arguments = ""
'  oLink.Description = "MyExe"
'  oLink.HotKey = "ALT+CTRL+F"
'  oLink.IconLocation = WScript.Arguments(0) & "\" & WScript.Arguments(1) & ", 2"
'  oLink.WindowStyle = "1"
   oLink.WorkingDirectory = WScript.Arguments(0)
oLink.Save
```

Save it as and then call

```
cscript "%~dp0" "MyExe.exe"
```

You can also create it from [powershell or various other tools](https://superuser.com/q/392061/241386)

```
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$lnk = $objShell.CreateShortcut("$home\Desktop\MyExe.lnk")
$lnk.TargetPath = ".\MyExe.exe"
$lnk.Save()
```

Comment: This looks like incorrect, `oLink.TargetPath = "MyExe.exe"` will create shortcut for C:\MyExe.exe

Comment: I didn't have time test those. Please modify it to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

This is I found:

```
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
userProfilePath = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")
currParentFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
linkPath = userProfilePath + "\Desktop\MyExe.LNK"
targetPath = currParentFolder + "\MyExe.EXE"
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(linkPath)
    oLink.TargetPath = targetPath
    oLink.WorkingDirectory = currParentFolder
oLink.Save
```